# How to mount a rod (rotating)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I want a rod to freely rotate 360°, it stands vertically and the rod is gonna carry some construction below it.
The rod should be fixated to the e.g. the wall or anything on a ceiling.

What parts do I need to make this possible? How do I fixate the rod onto the ceiling without stopping it's rotation?

I have looked up about eccentric locking collar, is this the standard solution? 
Or are there easier ways to fix the vertical rod (falling down the floor) without stopping its movement?

Comment: How much load? How fast will it rotate? Is the load off-centre?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fixate the rod onto the ceiling without stopping it's rotation?

With a [thrust bearing](https://www.mcmaster.com/thrust-bearings). A conventional bearing supports radial loads; a thrust bearing supports axial loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an old dead electrical drill's chuck and shank.

Or even hang the whole drill from the ceiling. 
If you need a bigger or stronger gadget, you can use an old industrial hammer drill or jack hammer tip.